# Laravel 7 - Form

Tags: php, laravel, forms, save, edit

I have a form to edit and update certain values ​​of a student, like grade, scholarship, comments, etc. And I have a `@foreach` so that I can update each student one by one, but I want to change that, I want to send all data of all students at the end, not one by one. Based on what I have, can I do that?

- StudentController

```
    public function enroll($id_student, request $request)
        {
            try {
                $idGroup = $request->get('idGroup');
                $student = Students::where('id_student', $id_student)->first();
                $student->groups()->attach([$idGroup => ['InvoiceNumber' => $request->get('InvoiceNumber'), 'Comments' => $request->get('Comments'), 'scolarship' => $request->get('scolarship') ? $request->get('scolarship') : 0]]);
                return back()->with('success', 'Student successfully enrolled');
            } catch (\Illuminate\Database\QueryException $e) {
                $message = $e->getMessage();
                if (strpos($message, "Duplicate entry")) {
                    return back()->with('err', 'This Student is already registered in this group');
                }
                if (strpos($message, "1366 Incorrect integer value: '' for column 'idGrupo'")) {
                    return back()->with('err', 'You must select a group to continue');
                }
                return back()->with('err', $message);
            }
        }
    
        public function enrollEdit($id_student, $idGroup, Request $request)
        {
            try {
                $student = Students::where('id_student', $id_student)->first();
                $group = $student->groups()->where('groups.idGroup', $idGroup)->first();
                $group->pivot->NumeroDeFactura = $request->get('NumeroDeFactura');
                $group->pivot->Comentarios = $request->get('Comentarios');
                $group->pivot->beca = $request->get('beca') ? $request->get('beca') : 0;
                $group->pivot->calificacion = $request->get('calificacion');
                $group->pivot->save();
                return back()->with('success', 'Enrollment edited successfully');
            } catch (\Throwable $th) {
                return back()->with('err', 'Error: ' . $th->getMessage());
                //throw $th;
            } catch (\Illuminate\Database\QueryException $e) {
                $mensaje = "There is already a student with that registered email";
                return back()->with('err', $mensaje);
            }
        }
```

- View

```
   
  @foreach ($group->students as $student)
     <tr>
        <td class="align-middle ">
            @if ($student->pivot->scolarship == 0 && $student->pivot->InvoiceNumber == '')<!--Validacion para imprimir icono de no pago-->
                <i class="material-icons text-danger">payment</i>
            @endif
            <i class="material-icons">{{$student->pivot->scolarship?'school':''}}</i>
            {{$student->Last_Name}} {{$student->Apellido_Materno}} {{$student->Names}}
        </td>
        <td class="align-middle text-center">
            <form method="post" action="{{url('Students/enroll/'.$student->id_student.'/'.$group->idGroup.'/edit')}}">  
                 {{csrf_field()}}
                 <input  {{$student->pivot->scolarship=='1'?'checked':''}} type="checkbox" name="scolarship" value="1"></td>
                 <td class="align-middle text-center"><input name="InvoiceNumber" type="text" value="{{isset($student->pivot->InvoiceNumber)?$student->pivot->InvoiceNumber:''}}" class="form-control form-control-sm" placeholder="Factura"></td>
                 <td class="align-middle text-center"><input name="grade" type="text" value="{{isset($student->pivot->grade)?$student->pivot->grade:''}}" class="form-control form-control-sm" placeholder="grade"></td>
                 <td class="align-middle text-center"><textarea name="Comments" type="text"  class="form-control form-control-sm" placeholder="Comments"  rows="1">{{isset($student->pivot->Comments)?$student->pivot->Comments:''}}</textarea></td>
                  <td class="align-middle text-center">
                      <button type="submit"  class="btn btn-sm btn-outline-warning"> @lang('show.Save')<i class="material-icons" style="font-size:20px">save</i></button>
                  </td>

                  <td class="align-middle text-center">
                       <form method="post" action="{{url('Groups/Disenroll/'.$group->idGroup.'?idStudent='.$student->id_student)}}">
                             {{csrf_field()}}
                             <button type="submit"  class="btn btn-sm btn-outline-danger"  > <i class="material-icons" style="font-size:10px">call_split</i></button>
             </form>
                 </td>
     </tr>
  @endforeach
```

Everything works fine but the view always reloads after saving the data of one of the students, so it is a bit tedious to be saving student by student quickly so that the modified information of the other students is not erased.

How could it be modified? Make the form send all the data without saving one by one.

Comment: Either use _one_ form to save them all or use AJAX to save each form individually

Answer (score 0):

You can create a post request using [jquery ajax](https://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/). So then you can update database without refreshing the page

Answer (score 0):

you must use:

```
<input  {{$student->pivot->scolarship=='1'?'checked':''}} type="checkbox" name="scolarship[]" value="1"></td>
```